# Can you help me please about fsck

Tags: boot, reboot, fsck, data-corruption, ash

[Check the image or ask me for details. Thanks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1AzLd.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Start a live session, using the Ubuntu installation DVD.

Then in the live session, open a terminal and run on it:

```
sudo umount /dev/sda7
sudo fsck /dev/sda7
```

Then reboot

And boot from hard drive

Comment: Thanks  it's fixed now!!